# PostgreSQL, развёртывание базы через pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как развернуть БД в pgAdmin с помощью скрипта load-pgsql.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
DB=movielens
set -e -x
dropdb --if-exists $DB
wget -c http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest.zip
unzip -o ml-latest.zip
createdb $DB
psql $DB < load-pgsql.sql
pg_dump $DB > ml-latest.sql
```

Ссылка: https://github.com/bozaro/tech-db-lectures/blob/master/scripts/movielens/load-pgsql.sh

по идее должна загрузиться и развернуться база данных с рейтингами фильмов, но открывая в запроснике в pgAdmin этот скрипт и выполняя его получаю, что скрипт успешно выполнен, но никаких данных не появляется. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

wget создаёт файл не в текущей директории. С вашими параметрами он создаст что-то типа директории files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ и туда уже запишет файл, где unzip его не найдёт. Проверьте, наличествует ли load-pgsql.sql в текущей.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно мыслите. Я предполагаю, что у вас линукс.

В этом скрипте не БД загружается, а данные в формате csv. Они находятся в архиве, при распаковке в текущем каталоге должно появится папка ml-latest, где несколько файлов csv. Перво-наперво проверьте, появилась ли эта папка и файлы из архива.

Затем запускается SQL-скрипт load-pgsql.sql - и в нем уже подгружаются данные из этих файликов.
Именно поэтому скорее всего, когда вы запускаете в pgadmin, скрипт выполняется, но из-за отсутствия csv-файлов данные не появляются.

Скачайте эту папку к себе на компьютер (а точнее репозиторий), запустите терминал (bash на линуксе), перейдите в этот каталог и поочередно запускайте вручную команды из этого скрипта. Просто откройте где-то этот скрипт, хоть в браузере и поочередно запускайте команды, смотрите вывод.

Если у вас не линукс, вам этот скрипт не поможет :) Но можно попробовать воспроизвести пошагово эти действия.

1. Скачать в какую то папку архив http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest.zip и распаковать его любым архиватором, главное чтобы появилась папка ml-latest с файлами из архива.
2. Скачать тудаже скрипты sql из репозитория, load-pgsql.sql обязательно, остальные не смотрел, но тоже желательно как есть
3. Запустить терминал (на Windows Powershell лучше всего), перейти в эту папку и в нем выполнить команды

   dropdb --if-exists movielens

   createdb movielens

   psql movielens < load-pgsql.sql

   pg_dump movielens > ml-latest.sql

Естественно я предполагаю, что у вас нормально на системе установлен postgresql, чтобы работали консольные утилиты psql и другие.